# Exception in reading list of Azure IoT devices in C# azure function

Tags: c#, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I'm fetching list of Azure IoT devices using IoT hub sql query in C# function.

```
 var query = _registry.CreateQuery("SELECT deviceId,tags.SiteId FROM devices", 100);
```

I'm getting below error in function while debugging

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: `shared_iot_eventhub_reader_function`. Microsoft.Azure.Devices: result type is Raw.

Same query works in Azure portal. What changes do I need to make in query to give me list of Azure IoT devices

[image]

I want to fetch a List of Azure IoT devices in my Azure IoT Hub

Comment: Please share your code where you instantiate `_registry` and where you execute/evaluate the `query` query. And tell us exactly on what call-site the exception is thrown: show the **full** stack-trace.

Comment: @Dai

My registry instantiation :
        `private static RegistryManager _registry = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString("HostName=xxx;SharedAccessKeyName=xxx;SharedAccessKey=xxx");`

Query handler :
 `while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                IEnumerable<Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared.Twin> lstDevices = await query.GetNextAsTwinAsync();
                foreach (var deviceTwin in lstDevices)
                {
                    
                    //do work on twin object
                    //count++;
                }
            }`

Comment: Why are you using `GetNextAsTwin` when your query only returns `deviceId` and `tags.SiteId`? You need to use specific queries to use `Twin` objects: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/query-twins

Comment: @Dai
changed to query.GetNextAsJsonAsync() and now it works. Thank you, I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Azure Function I was able to get the reading list of Azure IoT devices with `Twin` objects.

> I have referred this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language) for  IoT Hub query ,[Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?pivots=programming-language-csharp&tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cfunctionsv2) and for your comments @Dai

```cs
  
            var connectionString = "your connection string";
            var registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

            var query = registryManager.CreateQuery("SELECT * FROM devices", 100);
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                var page = await query.GetNextAsTwinAsync();
                foreach (var twin in page)
                {
              
                    log.LogInformation($"Device Id: {twin.DeviceId}");
                    log.LogInformation($"ModuleId :{twin.ModuleId}");
                    log.LogInformation($"Tags:{twin.Tags}");
                    log.LogInformation($"CloudToDeviceMessageCount :{twin.CloudToDeviceMessageCount}");
                    log.LogInformation($"StatusUpdatedTime :{twin.StatusUpdatedTime.ToString()}");
                    log.LogInformation($"twin.Properties:{twin.Properties.ToString()}");
                    log.LogInformation($"LastActivity :{ twin.LastActivityTime.ToString()}");
                    log.LogInformation($"Version: {twin.Version.ToString()}");
                }
            }

            await registryManager.CloseAsync();

            return new OkResult();
```

**Output** :

[image]