# IoTHub automatic configuration is reapplying after the device twin property was changed

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have an automatic configuration with a Target Condition: '*', it correctly applies and updates desired properties in twin.

When I update some properties in the device twin, that do not exist in the automatic config  I have the next flow:

- property is updated in twin
- device receives desired property updated event (contains all properties)
- (after a few minutes) device receives desired property updated event again (contains just props from automatic config)

I check the twin config after the last step, property values were not changed, but the version was increased, and in metadata adds the $lastUpdatedBy property which refers to the ID of the automatic config.

Until now, there was no such problem. Why does this last step happen?

**UPD:**
Below is a table containing logs for operations **C2DTwinOperations** and **D2CTwinOperations**.
As you can see from it, starting from the bottom, I read the configuration, and updated it, after which the update event occurred and the device read the configuration.

Then the configuration was read, although this is a read operation, it was at this time that the twin was updated, and the version was increased, you can also see that this operation occurs from a different version of the SDK than mine.

Then you can see that the device has read the data. He read 3035 bytes. That's how much the values in the automatic configuration take up. That is, the values that I updated in the twіn separately were not read.

| TimeGenerated | Category | OperationName | MessageSize | SdkVersion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6/9/2023, 4:45:43.000 PM | C2DTwinOperations | read | 0 | 2020-09-30 |
| 6/9/2023, 4:45:43.000 PM | D2CTwinOperations | read | 3035 | .NET/1.42.0 (.NET 6.0.16; Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 WindowsProduct:0x00000030; X64; |
| 6/9/2023, 4:43:38.000 PM | C2DTwinOperations | read | 0 | 2020-09-30 |
| 6/9/2023, 4:41:27.000 PM | D2CTwinOperations | read | 3469 | .NET/1.42.0 (.NET 6.0.16; Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 WindowsProduct:0x00000030; X64; |
| 6/9/2023, 4:41:27.000 PM | C2DTwinOperations | update | 3430 | 2021-04-12 |
| 6/9/2023, 4:41:27.000 PM | C2DTwinOperations | read | 0 | 2021-04-12 |

Comment: Hello, @Oleksandr how you are updating properties with sdk like c# (or) python?

Comment: Hi, @Sampath. I am using C# SDK
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp

Comment: your update and get the properties what properties  you are upadting

Comment: In general, nothing changed in my code when this problem arose.
I updates as follows:

`Twin twin = await _registryManager.GetTwinAsync(eventData.Esn);`
twin.Properties.Desired["propName"] = "propValue";
await _registryManager.UpdateTwinAsync(eventData.Esn, twin, twin.ETag);

Comment: will give will sample example to read the Properties and update the Properties

Answer (score 0):

> I have referred this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76173024/exception-in-reading-list-of-azure-iot-devices-in-c-sharp-azure-function/76181345#76181345) for getting data from IOT Hub.

[image]

```cs
var query = registryManager.CreateQuery("SELECT * FROM devices", 100); 
while (query.HasMoreResults)
 { 
 var page = await query.GetNextAsTwinAsync();
  foreach (var twin in page) 
  {  
twin.Properties.Desired["temperature"] = 72; 
twin.Properties.Desired["humidity"] = 50;
 twin.Tags["location"] = "Building A";
 twin.Tags["temperature"] = "72F"; 
registryManager.UpdateTwinAsync(twin.DeviceId, twin, twin.ETag); 
Console.WriteLine($"Device ID: {twin.DeviceId}");
 Console.WriteLine($"Location: {twin.Tags["location"]}"); 
 Console.WriteLine($"Temperature: {twin.Tags["temperature"]}"); 
 Console.WriteLine($"Desired Temperature: {twin.Properties.Desired["temperature"]}"); 
 Console.WriteLine($"Desired Humidity: {twin.Properties.Desired["humidity"]}"); 
 Console.WriteLine();
  }
   }
```

**Console Output:**

[image]

**In Azure:**

**Tags:**

[image]

**Desired Properties:**

[image]

**For the continuous change of Values:**

```cs
  Console.WriteLine("Do you want to change the values? (y/n)");
        var response = Console.ReadLine();

        if (response.Trim().ToLower() == "y")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the new desired temperature:");
            var newTemperature = Console.ReadLine();
            twin.Properties.Desired["temperature"] = newTemperature;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the new desired humidity:");
            var newHumidity = Console.ReadLine();
            twin.Properties.Desired["humidity"] = newHumidity;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the new location:");
            var newLocation = Console.ReadLine();
            twin.Tags["location"] = newLocation;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the new temperature tag:");
            var newTemperatureTag = Console.ReadLine();
            twin.Tags["temperature"] = newTemperatureTag;

            registryManager.UpdateTwinAsync(twin.DeviceId, twin, twin.ETag);
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Sampath. I can update desired properties. The problem is that I have applied automatic config, and it reapplies after when I change desired properties.

Comment: Try use time trigger  with iot hub for your case  refer [this](https://www.bizstream.com/blog/timer-triggered-azure-functions-in-c-with-net-6/)

Comment: I updated the properties values with properties values got reflected in Azure as well and  Make sure the desired properties values also changes .

Comment: @SPT I contacted Microsoft Azure support, if there is a solution, I will definitely share it.